# Using nsis to package application installer and .wav file does not play because of a path on Windows containing a space --> Program%20Files

Tags: java, windows, url

I'm running into an issue that involves an audioInputStream, a resource folder, and nsis for a Windows installation.  I'm working on an app (in Linux) that performs a desktop notification when an event occurs and everything works except for the .wav file that is supposed to play when the notification pops up.  I have tested the app on a 64 bit Windows machine without installing it via nsis and it works perfectly.  I received an error message indicating:

07/08/13 12:17:26 ERROR [Thread-2] (DesktopNotifierMessageAlertHandler.java:73) com.alcatel.proserv.e911.desktopNotifierMessaging.desktopNotifierMessageHandler.DesktopNotifierMessageAlertHandler - Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Alcatel-Lucent\E911DesktopNotifier\classes\audio\siren.wav (Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable)

I'm working in Netbeans and using maven to build.  Here is a code snippet of how I'm loading the path:

```
    String filename = this.getClass().getResource("/audio/siren.wav").getPath();
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
    try{
    audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename).getAbsoluteFile());
    Clip clip = null;           
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();       
clip.open(audioInputStream);        
    clip.start();
    }
    ...
```

I found this blog detailing how to fix an extremely similar issue:
http://braintwitter.blogspot.ro/2013/03/url-encoding-issue-with-tomcat.html

but it didn't work out with the audioInputStream I'm working with.

I know it's a problem with the space in "Program Files" which is where I have to set up the installation to occur because when I changed the InstallDir value in the setup.nsi script from $PROGRAMFILES64 to $WINDIR, it worked perfectly.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can modify my code to work properly since the space in Program Files is causing an encoding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getResource()` returns a `URL`, and it has URL encoding applied here. You have two options. You can convert to a `URI`:

```
String filename = this.getClass().getResource("/audio/siren.wav").toURI().getPath();
```

Or you can use `URLDecoder` to decode the path before passing it along to your `AudioInputStream`:

```
String filename = this.getClass().getResource("/audio/siren.wav").getPath();
filename = URLDecoder.decode(filename, "utf-8");
```

See the blurb at the end of the intro section for [`java.net.URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

Answer (score 0):

so I know this is pretty old thread, but anyone reading this, think twice, as the nsis packager creates this malware as scanned on virus total on a pc that's been run with malwarebytes, avira, roguekiller, hitman pro and stinger.

```
Antiy-AVL - Trojan/Generic.ASMalwS.3506C16,  Avast-Win64:Malware-gen, AVG - Win64:Malware-gen,  Cyren - W64/Tedy.B.gen!Eldorado, Jiangmin -Trojan.PSW.Python.fv, Zillya -Trojan.Disco.Script.653
```